# Is it possible to stream audio via Bluetooth over the same connection used to send Bluetooth commands?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Pi 4 that receives commands over Bluetooth from an iOS app to do things like play music stored on the Pi. I am considering making it so that the music need not be stored on the Pi, but is instead stored on the app and streamed to the Pi (the music tracks are proprietary). Since I currently use a Bluetooth Low Energy connection to send commands, I am wondering if it’s possible to send over audio files in chunks and play them back omxplayer without needing to wait for the whole file to land before playback.